# Where can I find logged mount errors?

Tags: linux, mount, logging

Where's the log where I can read mounting errors?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Sorry, linux :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a linux environment, dmesg should have them.

Check /var/log/dmesg